# How can get data from address-book faster in Android?

Tags: android, asynchronous, contacts, updates, addressbook

I create an application to get all contact in addressbook (phone book) of Android device like Viper application.

Here is my code:

```
private void Import_contacts_from_address_book() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String phoneNumber = null;
        String email = null;
        Uri CONTENT_URI = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
        String _ID = ContactsContract.Contacts._ID;
        String DISPLAY_NAME = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME;
        String HAS_PHONE_NUMBER = ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER;

        Uri PHONECONTENT_URI = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
        String PHONECONTACT_ID = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID;
        String NUMBER = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER;

        Uri EMAILCONTENT_URI = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI;
        String EMAILCONTACT_ID = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID;
        String EMAIL = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA;

        StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
        ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
        Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
        System.out.println("---------------------->"+cursor.getCount());
        if(cursor.getCount() >0){
            countContact = cursor.getCount();
            while(cursor.moveToNext()){
                String contact_id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(_ID));
                String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DISPLAY_NAME));
                int hasPhoneNumber = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)));


                //------------------- Catch phone number, neu phone >0 thi get phone, ko thi lam chuyen khac
                //if(hasPhoneNumber > 0 ){
                    output.append("\nFirst Name: "+name);
                    // Query and loop for every phone number of the contact
                    Cursor phoneCursor = contentResolver.query(PHONECONTENT_URI, null, PHONECONTACT_ID + "=?", new String[]{contact_id}, null);
                    while(phoneCursor.moveToNext()){
                        phoneNumber = phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(NUMBER));
                        output.append("\n Phone number: "+phoneNumber);
                    }
                    phoneCursor.close();
                    // Query and loop for every email of the contact

                    Cursor emailCurosr = contentResolver.query(EMAILCONTENT_URI, null, EMAILCONTACT_ID+"=?",new String[]{contact_id},null);
                    while(emailCurosr.moveToNext()){
                        email = emailCurosr.getString(emailCurosr.getColumnIndex(EMAIL));
                        output.append("\nEmail: "+email);
                    }
                    emailCurosr.close();
                //}
                output.append("\n");
            }
            cursor.close();
        }
        txtViewContactsInfor.setText("Contacts: "+String.valueOf(countContact));
        outputText.setText(output.toString());
    }
```

I try to import 1000 contact and it take at least 45 second.

- Is there any way to improve speed?
- And when I change some information in contact of addressbook (phone book) in Android device. I using onResume() to update new information for my application but It's reload all page so It take a long time. But I see on Viper, the data updating immediately. So, is there any I can update or sync data from my device to my application like Viper application or improve speed updating, reload page ?

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Query operation is very long operation on android, because each time, when you call query, system opens database file. Opening file is expensive in android. You should call query as rarely as possible. This is my solution:

```
    public class Contact {
        public String name;
        public List<String> phones;
        public List<String> emails;
    }

    private static final Uri CONTENT_URI = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
    private static final String _ID = ContactsContract.Contacts._ID;
    private static final String DISPLAY_NAME = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME;

    private static final Uri PHONE_CONTENT_URI = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
    private static final String PHONE_CONTACT_ID = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID;
    private static final String NUMBER = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER;

    private static final Uri EMAIL_CONTENT_URI = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI;
    private static final String EMAIL_CONTACT_ID = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID;
    private static final String EMAIL = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA;


    private Collection<Contact> importContactsFromAddressBook() {
        Map<String, Contact> contactMap = new HashMap<String, Contact>();
        ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
        Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                String contactId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(_ID));
                String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DISPLAY_NAME));
                Contact contact = new Contact();
                contact.name = name;
                contact.phones = new ArrayList<String>();
                contact.emails = new ArrayList<String>();
                contactMap.put(contactId, contact);
            }
        }
        cursor.close();

        // Query and loop for every phone number of the contact
        Cursor phoneCursor = contentResolver.query(PHONE_CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
        while (phoneCursor.moveToNext()) {
            String contactId = phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(PHONE_CONTACT_ID));
            String phoneNumber = phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(NUMBER));
            Contact contact = contactMap.get(contactId);
            contact.phones.add(phoneNumber);
        }
        phoneCursor.close();

        // Query and loop for every email of the contact

        Cursor emailCursor = contentResolver.query(EMAIL_CONTENT_URI, null, EMAIL_CONTACT_ID + "=?", new String[]{contactId}, null);
        while (emailCursor.moveToNext()) {
            String contactId = emailCursor.getString(emailCursor.getColumnIndex(EMAIL_CONTACT_ID));
            String email = emailCursor.getString(emailCursor.getColumnIndex(EMAIL));
            Contact contact = contactMap.get(contactId);
            contact.emails.add(email);
        }
        emailCursor.close();
        return contactMap.values();
    }
```